# RuntimeError: Event loop is closed when connecting python discord bot

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

I just started writing a discord bot with python and although the code is very simple, I somehow keep getting a RuntimeError when trying to connect

I checked the token multiple times

would really appreciate it if someone could tell me what I did wrong

python Script:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=':')


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('bot is ready')


bot.run('my_token')
```

here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\orang\Projects\PythonProjects\discord_lyrics_bot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 293, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "C:\Users\orang\Projects\PythonProjects\discord_lyrics_bot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 247, in request
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 401 Unauthorized (error code: 0): 401: Unauthorized

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\main.py", line 12, in <module>
    bot.run('Bxb-8dRGeYHYLFD5-IXGhNfY1TnX3kKA')
  File "C:\Users\orang\Projects\PythonProjects\discord_lyrics_bot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 718, in run
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\orang\Projects\PythonProjects\discord_lyrics_bot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 697, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\orang\Projects\PythonProjects\discord_lyrics_bot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 660, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\orang\Projects\PythonProjects\discord_lyrics_bot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 509, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\orang\Projects\PythonProjects\discord_lyrics_bot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 297, in static_login
    raise LoginFailure('Improper token has been passed.') from exc
discord.errors.LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed.
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x00000217D658C670>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\orang\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\orang\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "C:\Users\orang\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 719, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Users\orang\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 508, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the wrong discord token. First of all, you leaked your bot token

```
bot.run('Bxb-8dRGeYHYLFD5-IXGhNfY1TnX3kKA')
```

Regenerate your toek ASAP. Second, make sure you grab the token in the Bot Tab, and you don't get any of the other tokens. I can tell that the token is too short and is the wrong token.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you're using the `client secret` code, which is not your bot's token. What you have to do is go to [applications](https://discord.com/developers/applications) in Discord's Developer Portal. Once you're there, click on your bot application, and then go to the `Bot` tab on the left (it will have a little puzzle piece next to it). Over there, you should see `Click to Reveal Token` under `Build-A-Bot`. You can either click that and copy what shows up, or you can simply click the `Copy` button which will automatically copy the bot's token for you. Please do not share your token with anyone, as it can be used to run other people's code if they have access to it. If you've already leaked it, just go ahead and click the `Regenerate` button, which will give you a new token for your bot, and it will null the older token so that nobody can use your bot anymore.